# Angular Injector, have multiple InjectFlags in get method

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

https://angular.io/api/core/Injector#get

has argument `flags?: InjectFlags`. (https://angular.io/api/core/InjectFlags).

How can we have **multiple** InjectFlags?

Something for eg. that would resemble

```
@Optional() @SkipSelf() private _type1: Type1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@Optional() @SkipSelf()` is an equivalent for:

```
InjectFlags.Optional | InjectFlags.SkipSelf
```

Comment: Bitwise operators ... I get it now!